# Not able to get data of select Item using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a select option and input type text and a button for adding new rows with it's data.

I tried writing code for that, but while adding new rows on button click the data of select Item is not getting populated.

For more info below is the code

```js
var i=2;
  $(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td>"+i+".</td>";
        data +="<td><input type='select' id='first_name"+i+"' name='first_name[]'/></td> <td><input type='text' id='last_name"+i+"' name='last_name[]'/></td></tr>";
        $('table').append(data);
        i++;
});

$(".delete").on('click', function() {
 $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
    $('.check_all').prop("checked", false); 
 check();

});

function select_all() {
 $('input[class=case]:checkbox').each(function(){ 
  if($('input[class=check_all]:checkbox:checked').length == 0){ 
   $(this).prop("checked", false); 
  } else {
   $(this).prop("checked", true); 
  } 
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="http://demo.smarttutorials.net/auto_table/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
        <th>S. No</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>
        <td>1.</td>
       <td><select name="first_name[]" id="first_name" class="form-group">
     <option value="0">--Select--</option>
     <option value="1">Aisles &amp; common areas</option>
     <option value="3">BOH Storage area</option>
     <option value="2">Baggage Counter</option>
     <option value="6">CSD/Departmental POS</option>
     <option value="4">Cash room</option>
     <option value="5">Commercial Desk</option>
     <option value="7">Display area</option>
     <option value="8">Dock Doors</option>
     <option value="9">Electronic items area</option>
     <option value="10">Emergency exit</option>
     <option value="11">Escalator &amp; lifts</option>
     <option value="12">General surveillance areas</option>
     <option value="13">Goldsmith Room</option>
     <option value="16">High Value Accessories Rack</option>
     <option value="15">High pilferage</option>
     <option value="17">High value FMCG room</option>
     <option value="18">Inbound</option>
     <option value="19">Key Item Merchandiser</option>
     <option value="23">MPOS</option>
     <option value="20">Main Entry/Exit</option>
     <option value="21">Manager Room</option>
     <option value="22">Material Entry / Exit</option>
     <option value="24">Out bound Office</option>
     <option value="25">Outdoor Surveillance</option>
     <option value="27">Outside Trial rooms</option>
     <option value="26">Outside the frisking area</option>
     <option value="30">POS</option>
     <option value="28">Perimeter Area</option>
     <option value="29">Personal care</option>
     <option value="31">Power aisles to monitor customer movements</option>
     <option value="32">Racking area</option>
     <option value="33">ResQ Room/ Desk</option>
     <option value="34">Safe room</option>
     <option value="35">Sales floor</option>
     <option value="36">Saloon Entry /Exit</option>
     <option value="37">Shelving Area</option>
     <option value="38">Staff Entry / Exit</option>
     <option value="39">Staircase &amp; Fire Exit</option>
     <option value="40">Stock Room Exit</option>
     <option value="41">Vendor room</option>
     <option value="42">Wrap Desk</option>
     <option value="14">high end Cosmetics</option>

</select></td>
        <td><input type='text' id='last_name' name='last_name[]'/></td>
        
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    
     <button type="button" class='delete'>- Delete</button>
    <button type="button" class='addmore'>+ Add More</button>
    <p>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' class='but'/></p>
```

So how will I be able to get the data of select item.

For more info, see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w8sepayb/7/)

**UPDATE**

I added a radio button for more info of YES/NO like below

Below is the fiddle for the same

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53b46o9u/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way :

```js
var i = 2;
$(".addmore").on('click', function() {
  var data = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td>" + i + ".</td>";
  var select_data = $("#select_data").html();
  data += "<td>" + select_data.replace('id="first_name"', 'id="first_name'+i+'"') + "</td>";
  data += "<td><input type='text' id='last_name" + i + "' name='last_name[]'/></td></tr>";
  $('table').append(data);
  i++;
});

$(".delete").on('click', function() {
  $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
  $('.check_all').prop("checked", false);
  check();

});

function select_all() {
  $('input[class=case]:checkbox').each(function() {
    if ($('input[class=check_all]:checkbox:checked').length == 0) {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
    } else {
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="http://demo.smarttutorials.net/auto_table/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()" /></th>
    <th>S. No</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' class='case' /></td>
    <td>1.</td>
    <td id="select_data">
      <select name="first_name[]" id="first_name" class="form-group">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="1">Aisles &amp; common areas</option>
        <option value="3">BOH Storage area</option>
        <option value="2">Baggage Counter</option>
        <option value="6">CSD/Departmental POS</option>
        <option value="4">Cash room</option>
        <option value="5">Commercial Desk</option>
        <option value="7">Display area</option>
        <option value="8">Dock Doors</option>
        <option value="9">Electronic items area</option>
        <option value="10">Emergency exit</option>
        <option value="11">Escalator &amp; lifts</option>
        <option value="12">General surveillance areas</option>
        <option value="13">Goldsmith Room</option>
        <option value="16">High Value Accessories Rack</option>
        <option value="15">High pilferage</option>
        <option value="17">High value FMCG room</option>
        <option value="18">Inbound</option>
        <option value="19">Key Item Merchandiser</option>
        <option value="23">MPOS</option>
        <option value="20">Main Entry/Exit</option>
        <option value="21">Manager Room</option>
        <option value="22">Material Entry / Exit</option>
        <option value="24">Out bound Office</option>
        <option value="25">Outdoor Surveillance</option>
        <option value="27">Outside Trial rooms</option>
        <option value="26">Outside the frisking area</option>
        <option value="30">POS</option>
        <option value="28">Perimeter Area</option>
        <option value="29">Personal care</option>
        <option value="31">Power aisles to monitor customer movements</option>
        <option value="32">Racking area</option>
        <option value="33">ResQ Room/ Desk</option>
        <option value="34">Safe room</option>
        <option value="35">Sales floor</option>
        <option value="36">Saloon Entry /Exit</option>
        <option value="37">Shelving Area</option>
        <option value="38">Staff Entry / Exit</option>
        <option value="39">Staircase &amp; Fire Exit</option>
        <option value="40">Stock Room Exit</option>
        <option value="41">Vendor room</option>
        <option value="42">Wrap Desk</option>
        <option value="14">high end Cosmetics</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type='text' id='last_name' name='last_name[]' /></td>

  </tr>
</table>


<button type="button" class='delete'>- Delete</button>
<button type="button" class='addmore'>+ Add More</button>
<p>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' class='but' /></p>
```

Basically you add an id to the td containing the select `<td id="select_data">`, and then get it's html content everytime you click on the add button using

```
data += "<td>" + $("#select_data").html() + "</td>"
```

Comment: @BN happy to help :-) The only problem with this code is that it'll duplicate the `id='last_name'`, and you might want to have unique ids for each select ...

Comment: yes, I want id's to be unique so that I can use for saving it. any other way to get that ?

Comment: Sorry was busy.. will test and let u know :) thanks brother

Comment: did u checked my question mate ??

Comment: I added a radiobutton list which on add new row click is not getting fetched properly

Comment: @BN so when the first checkbox is checked you want the next added row have a checked box? Or new added checkbox depends on what? The last added row? You need to be more specific.

Comment: See, what exactly I want is.. The way select control and text control are getting binded in new row whenever I click on `add more` the same way I want to add the radiobutton in the new row. I tried like that but the css was not getting aligned properly. you can see my fiddle for more info

Comment: @BN like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sh69nwm3/)? (remove the `<br>` from HTML and JS if you want them in one line)

Comment: there are 2 bugs in our updated code, 1. If I delete all the rows, I am unable to add rows again. 2. The Second is, In each row atleast one radiobutton  should be checked. But here If check one the other loses its checked value..

Comment: @BN that's normal because to add rows it's always copying the first row, you can prevent this bug by preventing the deletion of the first row if there's only 1 row in the table using a simple if conditon `$('table tbody tr').length > 2` encapsulating your delete function, I'll let you figure out yourself how to implement it :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187725/discussion-between-b-n-and-islam-elshobokshy).

Answer (score 1):

Element Ids must be unique. Try cloning the element instead and creating a unique id. Use the jQuery clone function on the row. You are going to need to create an id for your original row (I assume an id of row1 in the example).

```
var lastRow = $('tr[id^="row"]:last'); // get last row
var num = parseInt(lastRow.prop('id').match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1; // get number in row id and add 1
var newRow = lastRow.clone().prop('id', 'row' + num);
newRow.insertAfter(lastRow);
```